# Understanding the authentication process of Salesforce Inspector for debugging Salesforce applications

Tags: google-chrome-extension, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-rest-api

I'm intrigued by the automatic login feature of Salesforce Inspector, and I'm curious about how it accomplishes this process. Does Salesforce Inspector utilize cookies and session information to automatically authenticate the user when connecting to a Salesforce org?

Specifically, I'm interested in learning:

1. What mechanisms does Salesforce Inspector employ to automatically log in users without requiring explicit authentication steps?
2. Does Salesforce Inspector rely on retrieving and utilizing existing cookies or session information from the user's browser to establish authentication?
3. If cookies and sessions are utilized, how does Salesforce Inspector retrieve and handle this information securely?

I've explored the available documentation and resources related to Salesforce Inspector but haven't found specific details regarding this automatic login process. Any insights, explanations, or references shedding light on how Salesforce Inspector achieves automatic authentication would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Salesforce Inspector tool intercepts the session ID of the currently logged-in user from the browser's cookie. Subsequently, it employs the acquired session ID to access information or invoke REST APIs within the Salesforce platform. In essence, the Salesforce Inspector does not manage the authentication process itself.

In below screenshot you can notice that there's one cookie named 'sid', value of it starts with '00D***'. That is the current user's session which Salesforce Inspector grabs and use for communication with Salesforce.

[image]

Comment: Can you help me with one SOQL request made with this SID?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm use postman, soapui or similar http client to execute a GET call similar to that documentation. Use "Authorization: Bearer (session id here)" header